# How to play vp9 videos on ubuntu

Tags: video, webm

So I have a vp9 video and I can not play the video on ubuntu 13.10 audio works because it is vorbis.

I have compiled ffmpeg version git-2013-11-01-ec5e02d

and I know that it supports vp9

Thank you in advanced

Comment: See this [Superuser](http://superuser.com/a/598322) thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok installed mpv player and it worked 
take a look at this 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187364&p=12845604#post12845604